# Rspec test failing on creating polymorphic has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, associations, integration

I have `Attachment` and `Answer` models. `Answer` has a polymorphic has_many relationship to `Attachment`:

In `Attachable` concern included in `Answer.rb`:

```
has_many :attachments, as: :record, dependent: :destroy
```

In `Attachment.rb`

```
belongs_to :record , polymorphic: true, optional: false
```

In my code flow, we create attachments that belong to another model before we create the answers. Basically, as you're completing the answer you create attachments that are stored and temporary belong to the user that is creating them. Then I submit all the answers with the already created attachment ids for each answer in the answer payload.

The answer payload looks something like and are stored in answer params:

```
{
  text: 'Answer response text',
  attachment_ids: [1,2]
}
```

Then in the controller, I create the answer and I'm hoping to update the attachments to belong to the newly created answer.

The code looks something like this:

```
Answer.create!({
  text: 'Answer response text',
  attachment_ids: [1,2]
})
```

Now the issue comes here.This logic is contained in a model method and in my Rspec model test, this fails to create update the `record` field on the attachments. However, this only fails in the test. In the console and in staging environment,  the create block above works correctly and sets the `Answer` <> `Attachment` relationships correctly.

To get my Rspec test to past I have to do something like this:

```
answer = Answer.create!({
  text: 'Answer response text'
})
answer.attachments << Attachment.where(id: [1,2])
```

Does anyone know why the Rspec test is failing while the top code block should work?

This is the expect blocks in my Rspec test:

```
expect(answer.reload.attachments).to eq [attachment]
expect(attachment.reload.record).to eq answer
```

I've tried a bunch of things including checking for attachments in different ways. I've also tested this in console and on staging and it works.

test failure:

```
expected: [#<Attachment id: 804, record_type: "Profile", record_id: 42994, type: "upload", created_at: "2019-08-09 14:35:39", updated_at: "2019-08-09 14:35:39", data: {}>]

got: #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```